# Excel connection manager failed with error code 0xC0202009

Tags: ssis, ssis-2008

I have ssis packages made  in Microsoft vs2008, for generating  reports in excel formats. For excel connection manager version excel version used is 'Microsoft Excel 97-2003. Till day before yesterday it was working fine. But from  yesterday it was throwing error for excel version. But when I changed version to ' Microsoft Excel 2007'. It works fine.
-No update in excel
-No update in vs2008.
- running package using SQL server agent

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There must be some more errorlogging, can you share that? And if it works with 2007 version why dont you just go with that then?

Comment: Another thing from error Iog is..Excel destination  validation validation and returned error code0x020801C.

Comment: It's in production environment.... I need it is difficult to change..

Comment: When you say it was working fine until yesterday, do you mean it worked fine in the production environment?

Comment: Yes..it was working in production envirnment till day before yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that one of the latest Windows Security updates broke the Excel/Jet driver. Workaround would be to uninstall one of the following (KB 4040685,KB 4041693, KB 4041687) and reboot the server